# Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load class

Tags: java, tomcat, server

Getting the following error when restarting tomcat.

```
Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load class ..The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact. java.lang.IllegalStateException:
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1743)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1701)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:437)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1428)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1372)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:474
```

I have tried restarting tomcat and also tried adding reloadable = false in server.xml

```
<Context path="/expert" docBase="expert" debug="0" reloadable="false">
```

Is there anything else that i can try?

Comment: Some libraries load new classes in their shutdown hooks. You should add the **whole** stack trace to the question.

Comment: @Piotr P. Karwasz  updated the stack trace

Comment: @divyanshugupta I don't see much stack trace in your question. Most stack traces have a `main` or `Thread.run` method at the bottom.